# How to install qemu emulator for arm in a docker container

Tags: docker, buildx

My goal is to build a [Docker Build](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) image that can be used as a CI stage that's capable of building a multi-archtecture image.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/docker:20.10.11-dind

# Add the buildx plugin to Docker
COPY --from=docker/buildx-bin:0.7.1 /buildx /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx

# Create a buildx image builder that we'll then use within this container to build our multi-architecture images
RUN docker buildx create --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --name=my-builder --use
```

^ builds the container I need, but does not include the emulator of `arm64`.  This means when I try to use it to build a multiarchitecture image via a command like `docker buildx build --platform=$SUPPORTED_ARCHITECTURES --build-arg PHP_VERSION=8.0.1 -t my-repo:latest .`, I get the error:

```
error: failed to solve: process "/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -y install -q ....
```

The solution is to run `docker run --rm --privileged tonistiigi/binfmt --install arm64` as part of the CI steps, which uses the `buildx` container I previously built.  However, **I'd *really* like to understand why the emulator cannot seem to be installed in the container** by adding something like this to the Dockerfile:

```
# Install arm emulator
COPY --from=tonistiigi/binfmt /usr/bin/binfmt /usr/bin/binfmt
RUN /usr/bin/binfmt --install arm64
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd really like to understand why the emulator cannot seem to be installed in the container

Because when you perform a `RUN` command, the result is to capture the filesystem changes from that step, and save them to a new layer in your image. But the qemu setup command isn't really modifying the filesystem, it's modifying the host kernel, which is why it needs `--privileged` to run. You'll see evidence of those kernel changes in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` on the host after configuring qemu. It's not possible to specify that flag as part of the container build, all steps run in the Dockerfile are unprivileged, without access to the host devices or the ability to alter the host kernel.

The standard practice in CI systems is to configure the host in advance, and then run the docker build. In GitHub Actions, that's done with the [setup-qemu-action](https://github.com/docker/setup-qemu-action) before running the build step.